# Django All-auth: Implement Login/Signup on Homepage Instead of Account/login or Account/signup

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-allauth

I'm currently attempting to build a website where the sign-up/log-in forms are not in their default location. I wish for the log-in form to be in a modal, and the sign-up form to just be located on the homepage. Has anyone done this before?

I've read this: [Log in / Sign up directly on home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427558/log-in-sign-up-directly-on-home-page/24179796#24179796)

But that doesn't seem to be the correct way to do it as it will still redirect to account/login or account/signup if there is an error.

EDIT: Still stuck on this.

Comment: Have you seen this question? It directly addresses putting the signup/login forms in a modal. The example site referenced is no longer available but the content of the answer remains directly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162108/implementing-ajax-requests-response-with-django-allauth

Answer (score 0):

It's all upto how you define login/logout urls and which view you call. You can even overwrite the existing ones.

[Django All Auth Installation](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html)

You can simply overwrite the existing urls and form as well. Also, one can write their own post request url to authenticate(login) or registration(signup)

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
```

and to authenticate in view

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user and user.is_active:
    login(request, user)
```