# Passing a dynamic state parameter using django-allauth during social login

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-allauth

I need to pass data through a social authentication (so I can access it after the login is complete) using django-allauth, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this as the documentation seems to be completely lacking in this area.

From what I gather, OAuth2 accepts a [state parameter](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) that can be used to transfer this sort of data. After spending hours trolling through the django-allauth code, it appears that there might be some ability to append a [dynamic state parameter](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/9e5b85f30b411ad7aedba3985ae486e803657189/allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth2/provider.py#L23). However, I have no idea what the proper way to introduce this data into the request is, nor at what point this should occur. Do I need to monkey patch something in socialaccounts/views.py? Unfortunately it doesn't seems like the socialaccounts adapter.py has any way to hook into a request like this.

Edit: It looks like there's also some opportunity to access the state parameter [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/9e5b85f30b411ad7aedba3985ae486e803657189/allauth/socialaccount/models.py#L162), but again, I'm unsure of the best way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the state parameters were a red herring; however, django-allauth passes the Django session ID through OAuth requests. This allows you to store data safely in `request.session` before the authentication occurs, and then access it again later after authentication is complete.

Comment: and how would you pass this data to backend on social login ?

Comment: This did not work for me using Google oAuth in allauth. The session parameter isn't preserved through the oAuth lifecycle.