# Django allauth problem with setting sessions params and getting them after login

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am using Django allauth to associate already logged in in Django users with their social accounts. For frontend I use Vue js, it sends in body pw and username.

My idea was to save Django user id in session parameters after login and grab it back during the allauth flow. As far as I understood it should work: [Passing a dynamic state parameter using django-allauth during social login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412369/passing-a-dynamic-state-parameter-using-django-allauth-during-social-login)

However, by some reason when I am trying to access the session parameter in allauth flow it is empty. The id is set in session and it should be fine. Currently, it is tested on Google OAuth2.

My login view:

```
@api_view(('POST',))
def login_user(request):
    # get credentials from Body
    request_data = json.loads(request.body)
    print(request_data)  # DEBUG
    username = request_data['username']
    password = request_data['password']
    try:
        # get user instance
        if not User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            raise ValidationError("The user does not exist")
        else:
            if username and password:
                # authenticate user
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                if not user:
                    raise ValidationError("Incorrect password or username")
                if not user.is_active:
                    raise ValidationError("This user is no longer active")
                print(user)  # DEBUG
                # set session cookie with user id
                print('SESSION UID', user.id) 
                request.session['user_id'] = user.id # works 
                session_uid = request.session.get('user_id', 'LOGIN NO SESSION UID')
                # get RefreshToken for user
                token_refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
                # response dict
                data = {'token': str(token_refresh.access_token), 'refresh_token': str(token_refresh)}
                # convert to utf-8 byte format for decoding
                access_token = bytes(str(token_refresh.access_token), encoding="utf-8")
                # decode token to get additional data
                valid_data = TokenBackend(algorithm='HS256').decode(access_token, verify=False)
                # add additional data to response dict
                data['uuid'] = valid_data['user_id']
                data['validUntil'] = valid_data['exp'] * 1000
                data['clientId'] = 'default'
                print(valid_data['user_id'])
                return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except ValidationError as v:
        return HttpResponse(f"Validation error: {v}", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise HttpResponse("User does not exists", status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

My allauth signals, I always get "User Id not found":

## EDITED

```
@receiver(user_logged_in)
def logged_in(request, user, **kwargs):
    print(user) # Here django creates a new user using the chosen gmail account from login popup
    request = kwargs['request']
    user_id = request.session.get('user_id', 'User Id not found')
    print('SESSION UID AUTH FLOW logged_in', user_id)


@receiver(pre_social_login)
def get_data(request, sociallogin, **kwargs):
    session_uid = request.session.get("user_id", 'User Id not found')
    print('SESSION UID AUTH FLOW get_data', session_uid) 
    print(request.user) # Here django creates a new user using the chosen gmail account from login popup
```

My adapter:

Here django creates a new user using the chosen gmail account from login popup

```
class MySocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
        user_request = request.user
        print('MySocialAccountAdapter', user_request, user_request.id, user_request.email)
        user = sociallogin.user
        if user.id:
            print('MySocialAccountAdapter', user.id)
            print('MySocialAccountAdapter', user.username)
            return
        if not user.email:
            return
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=user.email)  # if user exists, connect the account to the existing account and login
            print('MySocialAccountAdapter', user)
            sociallogin.connect(request, user)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            print('User does not exist')
            pass
```

Comment: Are you connecting to user_logged_in signal from allauth (https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html#allauth-account)? Looks like you're listening to the Django one

Comment: Yeah, I have just tested with request, user params in signal. By user I get newly created user.

Comment: im having th same issue, this ever get fixed properly?

Comment: @Maverick I did not find any solution and wrote my own methods without any third libs.