# How to implement django-allauth in homepage as modal?

Tags: django, django-allauth

There are few questions based on this idea like:

[Implementing Ajax requests / response with django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162108/implementing-ajax-requests-response-with-django-allauth)

[Log in / Sign up directly on home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427558/log-in-sign-up-directly-on-home-page/24179796#24179796)

https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/30lz11/django_allauth_implement_loginsignup_on_homepage/

but I need a little more help. I understand that I have to make form action url of modal as `{% url 'account_login' %}`. I have included `{% load account %}` and changed the 'name' and 'id' of username and password fields. My question is what other things I need to do to achieve this as it is still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question and I wrote little `tutorial` for 3 methods I found so far. You can find details at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235634/4992248

P.S. If it was just one method, I would post it here, but because I do not know which one you would prefer, I simply give you a link.