# Django AllAuth and Django Crispy Forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-allauth

I am trying to override the default `django-allauth` templates and use `django-crispy-forms` from improved rendering but having no luck getting the forms to actually submit, meaning I press submit and nothing happens.

Here is my `settings.py`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'about.apps.AboutConfig',
    'content.apps.ContentConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
]

...

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# All Auth settings

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

)

SITE_ID = 1

ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
```

Here is my custom template:

```html
{% extends "about/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
{% block navbar %}{% endblock %}

<div class="site-section mb-5">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="form-register">
     <form method="POST" class="signup" id="signup_form" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
         {% csrf_token %}
             <legend>Signup</legend>
             <div class="form-group">
               {{ form | crispy }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Sign Up">
            </div>
     </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I know the template is in the correct location and correctly overriding the `django-allauth` default templates because it renders, but why won't the submit button submit the form? I also know everything with `django-allauth` is working, because if I remove the custom template and use the `django-allauth` template, it will submit the form and redirect properly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this myself now. Really, I'd need to see the data for the {{ form|crispy }} to know exactly what is going on.

However, it isn't enough to simply render a similar form and submit. allauth has stuff running in the background (some of which is not entirely known to me).
I would recommend pulling the templates from the allauth github and editing them directly, removing tags you know are sure you don't need, like "extends 'allauth/base.html', headings, etc.. They're found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235634/13592328).

Then, I followed the details of the second method [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661581/how-to-implement-django-allauth-in-homepage-as-modal) to add the forms as context processors (most useful for my case use):

> **2. Contex processor**
>
> **a)** Make folder `your_project/your_app/context_processor`. Put there 2 files - `__init__.py` and `login_ctx.py`
>
> **b)** In `login_ctx.py` add:
>
> ```
> from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm
>
> def login_ctx_tag(request):
>     return {'loginctx': LoginForm()}
> ```
>
> **c)** In project's `SETTINGS` add `your_app.context_processors.login_ctx.login_form_ctx' in`TEMPLATES`
>   section. Something like:
>
> ```
> TEMPLATES = [
>     {
>         'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
>         'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates', 'allauth')],
>         'APP_DIRS': True,
>         'OPTIONS': {
>             'debug': DEBUG,
>             'context_processors': [
>                 'your_app.context_processors.login_ctx.login_form_ctx',  # <- put your
> ```
>
> processor here 
>                       'django.template.context_processors.debug',
>                       # [...other processors...]
>                   ],
>               },
>           },
>       ]
>
> **d)** In your `*.html` where you need add the next:
>
> ```
> {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
>     <form action="{% url 'account_login' %}" method="post">
>         {% csrf_token %}
>         <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}" />
>         {{ loginctx }}
>         <button type="submit">Login</button>
>     </form>
> {% else %}
>     {# display something else here... (username?) #}
> {% endif %}
> ```

So if you are rendering your own forms, I would recommend rendering the very same allauth forms instead in the custom template.

Add the crispy tag and all is good.